# How to sort search results to display the first user with picture and after the others in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with grouping and sorting.

```
(
    SELECT 
        `subdomain` AS `id`,`name`,`lastname`,IF(`category` NOT LIKE '',`category`,0) AS `category`,`level`,`image`,`description` AS `summary`, '1' AS `type`
    FROM 
        `user_professionals`
    WHERE `keywords`='%{$keywords}%' AND `active`='1' AND `search`='1' AND
        NULLIF(CONCAT(`name`, `lastname`), '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(`description`, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(`category`, '') IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY `image`, `id`
    ORDER BY `image` DESC
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        `id`,`name`,`lastname`,IF(`category` NOT LIKE '',`category`,0) AS `category`,`level`,`image`,`summary`, '2' AS `type`
    FROM 
        `users_amateurs` 
    WHERE `keywords`='%{$keywords}%' AND
        `on_hold`='0' AND (`level`='2' OR `level`='3') AND `register`='1' AND `banned`='0' 
    AND
        NULLIF(CONCAT(`name`, `lastname`), '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(`summary`, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(`category`, '') IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY `image`, `id`
    ORDER BY `image` DESC
)
LIMIT 100
```

### PROBLEM:

Searching must be in two separate tables at the same time what should give a combined result in one query. Sorting and grouping needs to go in the following order:

1. Professional Users with images
2. Professional Users without images
3. Amateur Users with images
4. Amateur Users without images

This query works very well but the problem is sorting.
Thanks!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I think I did not fully understand.